# jQuery Mobile Collapsible Sets, Open Multiple at Once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use the style of the Collapsible Set widget from jQuery mobile but have it function like a normal collapsible(e.g. allow more then one collapsible to be open at once within the collapsible set)?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html

Comment: First the link you give is from an alpha build, please see the updated documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible.html Also you could have a custom event to open any or all collapsible sets

Comment: Did you try to read this: 

Take a look on jquery demos:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html#/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible.html?
Allright, it's a block, but the functionality is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but you have to hack your way through like so:

```
$('.YOUR_COLLAPSIBLE_CLASS.ui-collapsible.ui-collapsible-collapsed')
    .attr('data-collapsed',false).removeClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")
    .find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass('ui-collapsible-content-collapsed');
```

You can do this with as many collapsibles in a set as you like. You have to somehow identify the collapsibles though.

I'm doing this in a form, so I'm starting form faulty form fields and work my way up to the collapsible set:

```
var el = my_faulty_form_field;

el.attr('placeholder', YOUR_ERROR_MSG)
    .closest('.ui-collapsible.ui-collapsible-collapsed')
      .attr('data-collapsed',false).removeClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")
        .find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass('ui-collapsible-content-collapsed');
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using a tiny hack but without any class attribute manipulation is to declare a new widget extending `collapsible-set` and unbind the unwanted event handler.

```
$.widget( "mobile.collapsiblegroup", $.mobile.collapsibleset, {
    options: {
        initSelector: ":jqmData(role='collapsible-group')"
    },
    _create: function() {
        $.mobile.collapsibleset.prototype._create.call(this);
        var $el = this.element;
        if (!$el.jqmData('collapsiblebound2')) {
            $el.jqmData('collapsiblebound2', true)
                .unbind('expand')
                .bind('expand', $._data($el.get(0), 'events')['collapse'][0]);
        }
    }
});

//auto self-init widgets
$( document ).bind( "pagecreate create", function( e ) {
    $.mobile.collapsiblegroup.prototype.enhanceWithin( e.target );
});
```

To use it, just change the `data-role` to `collapsible-group` instead of `collapsible-set`.

---

**Notice**: This works only with jQuery 1.8+, for older versions change

`$._data($el.get(0), 'events')` to `$el.data('events')`

Answer (score 2):

Additional explanation to frequent's answer:

```
$('.YOUR_COLLAPSIBLE_CLASS.ui-collapsible.ui-collapsible-collapsed')
    .attr('data-collapsed',false).removeClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")
    .find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass('ui-collapsible-content-collapsed');
```

i add these two lines:

```
$( '.YOUR_COLLAPSIBLE_CLASS h2' ).removeClass( 'ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed' );
$( '.YOUR_COLLAPSIBLE_CLASS h2 a' ).removeClass( 'ui-icon-plus' ).addClass( 'ui-icon-minus' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Collapsibles](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/collapsibles/#Setofindividualcollapsibles) instead of Collapsible Set or Accordion.

> The difference with a "Collapsible Set" is that multiple collapsible rows can be open at once.

Comment: Aka, just don't wrap your collapsible in a collapsible-set.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by stopping the event propagation after the main event is done.

```
$('.collaps').bind('expand', function (evt) {
  evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
})

$('.collaps').bind('collapse', function (evt) {
  evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

collaps is the name of the class you give to all the collapsibles in the set.
Then open and closing one does not affect the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your solution - although I had to do a minor change to make it work:

`stopImmediatePropagation` stopped any handlers to be executed, so nothing expanded or collapsed any more.

Using `stopPropagation();` does the job for me:

```
$('.collaps').bind('expand', function (evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
});

$('.collaps').bind('collapse', function (evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
});
```